# Посчитать количество значений в столбцах датафрейма в Питоне

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Как посчитать кол-во фильмов на разных стриминговых сервисах? 0=присутсвует, 1=отсутсвует.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.read_csv("MovieDF_French.csv")
df1.head()
```

[image]

Желаемый результат:

```
Netflix 528
Hulu    12      
Prime Video 30 
Disney+  28
```

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы кто-то сделал вашу работу за вас?

Comment: нет я только,  учусь и никак не могу решить это

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Команда ниже даст желаемый результат:

```
df[['Netflix','Hulu','Prime Video','Disney+']].sum()
```

Успехов!

Comment: Спасибо Большое!